# sending AJAX request which object

Tags: jquery

I am using AJAX in a jquery and try to send a request to given URL location in AJAX, but request is not sending.

```js
var obj = {
  a: $('#id').val();
  b: $('#name').val();
}

$.ajax({
  type: 'ajax',
  url: 'http://localhost/Codigniter_1/index.php/Data/dlt',
  method: 'post',
  data: obj,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="id">
<input type="text" id="number">
```

Comment: you have a typo (ajax brackets not closing) check your browser´s console

Comment: @hans Raj run the snippet . you will find the error

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in your code is wrong :

```
<script>
 var obj={     
    a:$('#id').val(),
    b:$('#name').val()
  }
  $.ajax({
        type: 'Post', //change the type attribut value
        url: 'http://localhost/Codigniter_1/index.php/Data/dlt',
        //method: 'post', // remove this line           
        data:obj,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
             // Do something with the response
        })
  });
</script>
```

the `type` attribut must be "Post" or "Get" and their is no `method` attribut.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: line number ?   and can you tell me correct syntax?

Comment: the code in my answer is the correct syntax. you must change the `type` attribut and remove the `method` attribut

Comment: object I created is correct? I think something is wrong in my object, like syntax issue

Comment: @HansRaj Your `inputs` don't have values.

Comment: @HansRaj i edited the code. now your object is correct. you must use `,` instead of `;`

Comment: yeah got it, Now the problem is resolved. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery and you just want to post an object, you could use jquery's shorthand $.post(); method.

```
    $.post('http://localhost/Codigniter_1/index.php/Data/dlt', obj);
```

after the ajax call chain whatever callback you need and it is always good to mind deprecation notices since youre using jquery 3.

**Deprecation Notice**: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
  a: $('#id').val();
  b: $('#name').val();
}

$.post('http://localhost/Codigniter_1/index.php/Data/dlt',obj,(response)=>console.log(response));
```